# pyspark sum of rows to get one new row based on values in another column in groupby

Tags: python, join

Have a dataframe which has user, location, values. Currently US related location are in different rows for one user:

```
user     location   values
209       OH_US          45
O09       PA_US          30
O09       AQ             10
209       CA_US          50
209       UK             10 
....
```

For each user want to generate a new row to replace US related locations with a  sum and location name is 'US'.Remove those rows in different states in US.
Expected result looks like this:

```
user     location   values
209       US          200
209       UK          10
O09       US          300
O09       AQ          10
...
```

Currently I'm thinking to pull all  US  related rows to a separate  dataframe to do a sum in groupby, then drop all the rows related to US in original dataframe to join with the US sum dataframe.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there can we multiple approach to solve this in pyspark

1. Using spark.sql -

> ```
> df.createOrReplaceTempView("SAMPLE_TABLE")
>
> df.createOrReplaceTempView("SAMPLE_TABLE")
>
> df2=spark.sql("SELECT user , case when location like '%_US' then 'US' else location end Location , SUM(VALUES) VALUES  from SAMPLE_TABLE group by user , case when location like '%_US' then 'US' else location end ")
>
> df2.show()
> ```

2. Using pyspark api

   ```
   import pyspark.sql.functions as F

   df.groupby(F.when(F.col('location').\
   like("%_US"),"US").\
   otherwise(F.col("location")).\
   alias('location'))\
   .agg(F.sum('values').alias("values"))\
   .show()
   ```